# Blank int field saving 0 to DB

Tags: php, mysql, int

I have an output for example `["payeeAccount"]=> string(0) ""` an empty string how can I make sure if its empty save empty and not insert a '0' into my db table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$payeeAccount = ( is_string( $payeeAccount ) && !empty( $payeeAccount ) ) ? $payeeAccount : '';
```

Save this variable to db.

Comment: Have to wait 5 min :)

Comment: Note that "empty" does not only mean "zero length string", but also "string with a zero in it" besides several other values. See http://de1.php.net/empty So that line of code effectively really does nothing besides also changing `"0"` into `""`, if the data source will only emit strings (which we don't know) - and transforming a zero in a string into an empty string could be considered a bug. If that field should not allow "strange" values as an account number, do proper validation.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the string is empty string "", and if it is then change it to "null"

Well, it depends on if you are using prepared statements or not.  If you are just concatenating into an sql string, use "null".  With prepared statements you might want to use null.

Comment: You mean to `null`, not `"null"`. And the database field must allow NULL to be a valid value.